# Unable to resolve constructor for: ' dojox.mobile.RoundRectCategory'

Tags: html, dojo, ibm-mobilefirst, dojox.mobile

I use Worklight 5.06 and Dojo 1.8.
After an Eclipse crash it shows this errors on browser's console:

1. Unable to resolve constructor for: 'dojox.mobile.RoundRectCategory'
2. Left list not found
3. this.leftList is indefined

As you can see in this screenshot:
[image]

```js
 dojo.connect(window, "onload", function() {
    dojo.require("dijit.form.NumberSpinner");
  });
function dojoInit() {


    require(["dojo", "dojo/request/script", "dojo/parser", "dojox/mobile", "dojox/mobile/compat", "dojox/mobile/deviceTheme",
          "dojox/mobile/ScrollableView",
          "dojox/mobile/ScreenSizeAware",
          "dojox/mobile/FixedSplitter",
          "dojox/mobile/Container",
          "dojox/mobile/EdgeToEdgeList",
          "dojox/mobile/RoundRect", n ",
               "
          dojox / mobile / Button ",
               "
          dojox / mobile / GridLayout ",
               "
          dojox / mobile / Pane ",
               "
          dojox / mobile / ScrollablePane ",
               "
          dijit / form / DataList ",

               ],);
```

```css
 @import url("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8/dojo/resources/dojo.css");
 @import url("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css");
```

```html
 <script type='text/javascript' src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js' data-dojo-config="parseOnLoad:true, async:'legacyAsync'"></script>

<div id="xx" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ScrollableView">

  <h2 data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.RoundRectCategory" style="text-align: center;">Filtro</h2>
  <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.RoundRect">
    <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Pane" style="text-align: center;">
      <input id="lll" type="text" onblur="ordinaItemCataloghi('cc')">
      <input id="ddd" type="text" placeholder="Descrizione catalogo" onblur="ordinaItemCataloghi('dd')> 
     <input id=" linea_prodotto " type="text " placeholder="Linea prodotto "
      onblur="ordinaItemCataloghi( 'll') ">
    </div>
   </div>  
   <h2 data-dojo-type=" dojox.mobile.RoundRectCategory "
    style="text-align: center; ">Elenco
     cataloghi
     </h2>
     <ul id="ulElencoCataloghi "></ul>
    </div>
```

everything worked up before the crash of eclipse. What could have happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Clean** your proyect on Eclipse
2. edit this row

   ```
   <input id="ddd" type="text"placeholder="Descrizione catalogo" onblur="ordinaItemCataloghi('dd')**"**>
   ```

   and

   ```
   <h2 data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.RoundRectCategory" style="text-align: center;">Elenco cataloghi</h2>
   ```
3. require only:

   ```
   "dojox/mobile/RoundRect",
   ```

Comment: After cleaning the project and add the double quotes it works.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Few things I notice:

1. In your `require()` you have some weird thing after `dojox/mobile/RoundRect`. That `` `n", `` doesn't belong there I suppose?
2. You didn't add a module called `dojox/mobile/RoundRectCategory` in your `require()`
3. Can you also post the callback of the `require()`? It's probably a mismatch between the name of the module and the position of the parameter in the callback. Without callback it's hard to find out (or to eliminate this possibility).

Comment: `n", is an error of paste and code. I delete dojox/mobile/RoundRectCategory but don't work anyway

Answer (score 0):

I got similar error with a Dojox DataGrid and migrating from 1.8 to 1.10. in my case it turned out the dot notation required to be changed to slash notation:

```
<!-- Change syntax from: -->
<table id="resultsUsers" data-dojo-type="dojox.grid.DataGrid">

<!-- Change syntax to: -->
<table id="resultsUsers" data-dojo-type="dojox/grid/DataGrid">
```